# Redux Map Store by props name

Tags: reactjs, redux

Redux Map Store by props name.

```js
const mapStore = (state, ownProps) => {
  const name = ownProps.name;
  return {
    value: state.[name] //<= help here
  };
};
```

Comment: I think you are looking for state[name] (notice no 'dot')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your issue is the `.` after state, this should solve your problem.

```js
const mapStore = (state, ownProps) => {
  const name = ownProps.name;
  return {
    value: state[name] // No period after state
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const mapStore = (state, ownProps) => {
  const name = ownProps.name;
  return {
    value: state.name //assuming state is an object with a key - name
  };
};
```